# Wait for another observable before proceeding

Tags: angular, rxjs

I don't know if I should post any code for this. But I will if required. I have an Angular2 directive, `MyDirective` and a service `MyService`

The service makes an http call in its constructor to fetch something and store in say `this.list`.

Directive injects the service and uses it as `myService.isPresent(item)`.

Now, the problem is that by the time directive executes, the http call for fetching the list in the service isn't completed. Is there a clean way to make the directive wait till the service is ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, since the http calls are always asynchronous you can't synchronously wait for them.

You can however instantiate the service with the `ReflectiveInjector` yourself and call the initialization before bootstrapping your app to be sure everything has loaded.

In the `bootstrap` call just provide your `MyService` instance with the data.

```js
//import ... from ...
import {MyService} from './my.service';

let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([HTTP_PROVIDERS, MyService]);
var myService: MyService = injector.get(MyService);

myService.init()
  .subscribe(data => {
    bootstrap(App, [
      HTTP_PROVIDERS,
      provide(MyService, {useValue: myService})
    ])
    .catch(err => console.error("error: ", err));
  });
```

In your `MyService` add this `init` method returning an `Observable` for your data loading:

```js
init(): Observable<any> {
  if (!this._initialized) {
    this._initialized = true;
    return this._http.get(this._url)
      .map(data => { 
        this._data = data.json();
        return this._data;
      });
  }
  else {
    console.log("Already initialized!");
  }
}
```

---

> [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/p1MopqhB1xgfFV2bua4f?p=preview) with a working example

Comment: But then this will result in multiple http requests right? How can I only make one http request and prevent all subsequent `loadData` calls to ignore (but give them callback once the first call gets completed)

Comment: So the data stays the same for the whole runtime?

Comment: Yes, its just an initial call to fetch and cache. May be there's a better approach?

Comment: Okay, so I tried and built something which solves your problem. Going to update my answer in a minute.